# How to extract an array from a script

Tags: php, preg-match, domdocument

Below I have a sample HTML. In the HTML there is a script. In the script there is an array. I want to extract this array. Preferably as an array in PHP but also extracting it as a string is also good. I don't understand how to target that part of the script. The part of the script I want to extract is: `(1234567, 111, 'Red Pants', 'https://example.com/red', '', 1, '','','0','0','0', 'buy')`.

It seems that the node value is the entire script. I am unsure how to isolate it.

PHP

```
<pre><?php

$content = file_get_contents("test.html");

$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($content);
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;

foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName('script') as $scripts) {

    var_dump($scripts);

}
```

HTML

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Example Domain</title>

    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
</head>
<script>


function init() {
    YAHOO.util.Event.on(['adding_to_cart','adding_to_trolley_sub'], 'click', addProdToTrolley);
    YAHOO.util.Event.on('add-prod-to-watchlist', 'click', addProdToWatchList);
    YAHOO.util.Event.on(['buy_now','buy_now_sub'], 'click', function() { SHOP.Purchase.buy(1234567, 111, 'Red Pants', 'https://example.com/red', '', 1, '','','0','0','0', 'buy');});
    YAHOO.util.Event.on(['frm_buttons','frm_buttons_sub'], 'submit', function(e) { YAHOO.util.Event.stopEvent(e); });
};

var id = 1234567;

function addProdToTrolley(e) {
    YAHOO.util.Event.stopEvent(e);
    document.trolley_quantity.trolley_action.value = 'Add to cart';
    document.trolley_quantity.tid.value = '';
    document.trolley_quantity.prod_id.value = id;
    disableButtons();
    document.trolley_quantity.submit();
};

</script>
```

Comment: Unfortunatly, you can't parse javascript with DOM. You have to use a javascript parser applied to your `$script` variable. [Here is a javascript parser](https://github.com/mck89/peast)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `regex` and extract from `HTML` content without xml dom:

```php
preg_match_all('/<script\b[^>]*>(.*?)<\/script>/is', $html, $matches);
```

And use substr to target starting with `SHOP.Purchase.buy(` to end of array in `;});`

or directly use regex to extract the JS data:

```php
preg_match_all('/SHOP.Purchase.buy(.*?);}\);/is', $string, $matches);
```

now `$matches[1][0]` is extracted data inside of script:

```
(1234567, 111, 'Red Pants', 'https://example.com/red', '', 1, '','','0','0','0', 'buy')
```

you can use `preg_match` if you want to find first matched script instead `preg_match_all`.